# Get models that has relationship in other collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models with a many-to-many relationship. FORM and WORKSPACE.
So FORM belongsToMany WORKSPACE, and WORKSPACE belongsToMany FORM.

Now I need to do a query where I get all FORMs that belong to any of the WORKSPACEs in a collection ($workspaces).
Something like this:

```
$forms = Form::whereHas('workspaces', function ($q) use ($workspaces) {
                $q->whereIn('id', $workspaces);
            })->get();
```

I know this query doesn't work. But I hope it explains what I need to do. I basically need to get all FORMs that has a WORKSPACE that's present in the $workspaces collection.

Any ideas on how to do this clean and nice?

Comment: It will work, if `$q->whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);` `$workspaces` contains indexed array? Need to know, what it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up the relationships correctly, you should be able to achieve this with something like:

```php
$workspaceIds = $workspaces->pluck('id');

$forms = Form::whereHas('workspaces', function ($query) use ($workspaceIds) {
    $query->whereIn('workspace.id', $workspaceIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: The relationships are setup correctly (as far as I can tell). I can get the Form models from a Workspace and vice versa, via the relationships. I already tried the way you suggested and I get this: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `forms` where exists (select * from `workspaces` inner join `form_workspace` on `workspaces`.`id` = `form_workspace`.`workspace_id` where `forms`.`id` = `form_workspace`.`form_id` and `id` in (1)) and `forms`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: This might work though: ... $query->whereIn('workspaces.id', $workspaces); ...

Comment: I edited it a bit (it must be table.column), and checked it as correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I've been using the column name in the pivot table which should work all the same without the additional lookup!

Comment: Aha. Didn't see that one. I'll try that out too. Anyways... Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.